# Css div responsive design

Tags: css

I have 2 divs inside one container div:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

This is how it should work:

Left one if fixed size, right one should be responsive and should have minimum and maximum width, which means if you shrink window width, right div should just shrink its width! (in between its min and max width) and stay on the right of the left div!, until width of the container div becomes smaller than left div width + right div min width, then right div should fall below left div!

http://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lj/6/

Width current css, green div should shrink its width with between 200 and 500px, while staying on the right of left div, only if container div becomes smaller than 400 (width of both divs) then green div should fall below blue div.

Thank you!

Comment: Your fiddle works fine.

Comment: It doesnt work the way I described, the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`min-width` and `max-width` don't work like that: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/max-width/

If you can use `calc`, this is one way to do it: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lj/8/)**

```
.right {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

If not, you can do the following: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lj/9/)**

This assumes that the height and width of `.left` are set numbers.

```
.left {
    position:fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.right {
    margin-left: 200px;
    min-width:200px;
    width: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    .right {
        width: 100%;
        clear: both;
        margin-left: 0;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the calc work in all browsers? In second demo, can the right div also have max width, so when it falls into new line it keep its width?

Comment: You can just set `width: 400px` if you want it to have an explicit width.

Comment: Can left in second demo be other than fixed position? Because how do  I move the whole container then so that left keeps position?

Comment: You can use `position: absolute`, but you'll need to make a couple other changes to make it visible under 400px: http://jsfiddle.net/5m8Lj/16/